# Filtering Azure Backup Jobs using ODATA in the REST API

Tags: rest, azure, odata, odata-v4

I'm trying to use the Azure REST API to receive the Recovery Services backup jobs from the last 24 hours.  The API appears to default to jobs that match the current UTC date.

As far as I can tell, Azure is using ODATA v4, so I would expect the query `$filter=startTime gt (now() sub duration P1D)` to work.  However, when I execute my script, it appears to ignore the filter and execute its default (current UTC date only).

The [documentation for the API method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/backupjobs/list) has examples using explicit dates that appear to be formatted as `Edm.DateTime`, even though the startTime property appears to return in `Edm.DateTimeOffset` format.  But I'm not finding any documentation for calculating the date within the $filter query.

A copy of my script is below.  Has anyone been able to do something like this against the Azure REST API?

```
$ListRSVaultsParams = @{
    Uri     = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/' + $SubscriptionID + '/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults?api-version=2018-01-10'
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = $AuthHeader
    }
}

$Vaults = (Invoke-RestMethod @ListRSVaultsParams).value
$Jobs = ForEach ($VaultId in $Vaults.id)
{
    $Results = @()
    $JobUri = 'https://' + $BaseHost + $VaultId + '/backupJobs?api-version=2018-01-10&$filter=startTime gt (now() sub duration P1D)'
    do
    {
        $JobParams = @{
            Uri     = $JobUri
            Headers = @{
                Authorization = $AuthHeader
            }
        }
        $JobResults = Invoke-RestMethod @JobParams
        $Results += $JobResults.value
        $JobUri = $JobResults.nextLink
    } while ($JobResults.psobject.name -contains 'nextLink')
    $Results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we don't support all values supported by OData format yet. Start Time and End Time represent the start/end of the range query. Can you please use something like,
`$filter=startTime eq 'string representation of DateTime'` instead of greater than?

Comment: I'd prefer not to.  The idea is to get backups from the last 24 hours, not backups from an exact date.  To do it using the string representation of an exact date, I'd have to run the query twice: one for "yesterday" and one for "today"

Comment: Currently we don't support non string inputs. You can use startTime and endTime but with a string as an input and not by specifying now(). Sorry for that. We will enhance to support OData functionality.